# Is it still possible to get a FB ID from knowing a users facebook e-mail

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It used to be the case, that you could query a users FB ID via the graph api using something like: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=email@gmail.com&type=user. However this particular query is not working, and I seem to remember, that this functionality was removed.

My case is, that I am getting facebook e-mail addresses by running lead ads on facebook. I want to then create accounts for these users on my website and connect their accounts to their facebook accounts.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or is there a smart workaround?

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: oh well thanks anyway.

Comment: if you want to create account in your own website than you may use facebook based authentication. It may help you

Comment: the problem is that I don't get the people on my website. They fill out their e-mail adress on a facebook ad and i only get the e-mail address from facebook.